# How to get the index number inside a for loop

Tags: python

This is my dataset:

```
dataset = [['A','B','C], ['D','E','F']]
```

I want the INDEX in this for loop.

```
for x in dataset:
  print ?????
```

I also tried this and many other things:

```
print(x.index())
prit(index(x))
etc..
```

All return errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `enumerate` as follows :

```
for ind, x in enumerate(dataset) :
  print(ind)
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Is it possible also to access the value of the item?

Comment: LOL, I get it !

Comment: If this answer fits you, I'd appreciate you validate it please ;)

Comment: Sure, I was expecting - points like hell, because stack overflow hates begginers so I'll accept it for sure!

Answer (score 1):

To make the answer more understandable because i'm not a fan of 'use this function it just works' (it's efficient but usually lacks teaching) the enumerate funtions works just like:

```
#values = your list
index = 0
for value in values:
    print(index, value)
    index += 1
```